# Is jquery code can mix in with d3.js?

Tags: d3.js

It's just a question. Sometimes when I use d3.js after I create object then I need to do some event or get some specific attribute by jQuery. The jQuery code just sometimes doesn't work but some other times it works.
Did any one ever been this before?

Comment: can you show some examples?

Comment: I can use github to share my code.
Because if i use live editor there isn't have this problem.https://github.com/PVClioujay/d3-StarField.git

Answer (score 1):

One thing I encountered is that jQuery's `addClass`, `removeClass`, `toggleClass` doesn't work on SVG (d3.js creates SVG elements), that's because The HTML and SVG DOM extensions have different definitions for "className". More details in this [article](https://toddmotto.com/hacking-svg-traversing-with-ease-addclass-removeclass-toggleclass-functions/).

Another thing is event handler, for example, when I bind a jQuery event handler on a selection element, I have to get the data on the SVG element by using `this.__data__`. Although it might be easier to just use d3.js event handler combined with `dispatch` event, `rebind`, etc. Besides, [manually triggering](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/100) event in d3 can be quite different than jQuery, such as:

```
var event = document.createEvent('Event');
event.initEvent('change', true, true);
d3.select("#element").node().dispatchEvent(event);
```